# My windows universal app always opens in full screen even when I tell it not to

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I set the preferred launch windows size like this below as my GUI was designed using a phone emulator so it looks better when I open in in this size, recently though my page has been opening in fullscreen now and I dont know why.

```
// Sets the size of the window on open
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(432, 768);
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

Comment: What operating system are you running the app on?

Comment: Windows 10!!!!!

Comment: One exclamation mark is more than enough! In windows 10, when you have tablet mode enabled, all metro apps are displayed in fullscreen. Maybe you turn off tablet mode?